# Passing a Property to a function and setting the value to be retained

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two properties setup as ViewControllers that each use different NIB file. (Male and Female Models, will function the same but are setup visually different.)  I want to have one function to create the ViewController based on the NIB Name and ViewController I pass in.

What's happening is the ViewController property is not being retained.  If I add the actual property name within the function and set it, the viewController is set and retains the ViewController.  Here is what I have in the .m file (Only showing what is needed to get help on.)  I've kept in the two comment lines that I tried to do determine where the problem was.

```
@synthesize femaleModelViewController;
@synthesize maleModelViewController;


    - (void) loadModelViewControllerWithModelType:(NSString*) model ModelView:(ModelViewController *)modelViewController {
        ModelViewController *viewController = [[ModelViewController alloc] initWithNibName:model bundle:nil];
    //  [self setFemaleModelViewController:viewController];  // I don't want to set the property here, I want to be able to pass it as an argument.
        modelViewController = viewController;
    //  [modelViewController retain]; // I even tried to retain it do see if would but it doesn't.
        [viewController release];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self loadModelViewControllerWithModelType:@"FemaleModel" ModelView:femaleModelViewController];
        [self loadModelViewControllerWithModelType:@"MaleModel" ModelView:maleModelViewController];


}
```

In the .h file my Properties are setup like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ModelViewController *femaleModelViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ModelViewController *maleModelViewController;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to assign a new `ModelViewController` to `maleModelViewController` and `femaleModelViewController`? If so, you're going about it the wrong way.

Frankly, I'd do away with the `loadModelViewControllerWithModelType:modelView:` method altogether. All you would need to do in `viewDidLoad` is this:

```
maleModelViewController = [[ModelViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MaleModel"];
femaleModelViewController = [[ModelViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FemaleModel"];
```

(This assumes that `maleModelViewController` and `femaleModelViewController` are the instance variables backing the properties of the same name.)

When you pass in `maleModelViewController` and `femaleModelViewController`, you're not passing a reference to those variables, you're passing their values. Since they haven't been initialized, all you're doing is passing in `nil`. To do what you're trying to do, you'd need to pass a *pointer* to the variables (i.e. declare the parameter as `ModelViewController **`, pass it in as `&maleModelViewController` and `&femaleModelViewController` and assign it using `*modelViewController = viewController`. If you're used to using pass-by-reference friendly languages like C# or Java, you should read up on how it works in C. (The rules are the same in Objective-C as in C).

HOWEVER, that is still complete overkill for what you're trying to do here.

Also, your code would still not work because you turn around and release `viewController`. This would cause it to be immediately deallocated, since the only reference you had to it came from when you `alloc`ed it. You would be assigning a dead reference that would crash your program as soon as you tried to use it.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I totally forgot to pass it via the Address and the value.  Going back and forth between Objective-C and C# can do that.

Yeah this sample seems like overkill but there will more going on in the method than simply declaring it.  If I retain it here it should work correct?

Comment: Retain where? There are two ways to get a retained reference to an object: `alloc` it, or `retain` it. If you've allocated it, you don't need to retain it too. Also, even if you have more initialization to do, it would belong in the `initWithNibName:owner:` method of the view controller, not whatever class this is. Don't bind your classes too tightly together or the whole application becomes fragile.